# Remove duplicates based on multiple properties, but not all

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given an array on objects and an object, looking something like this:

```
var historyList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Donna', data: 'phone: 903489349'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 1'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 2'}
]

var newHistoryObject = { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'phone: 03492'}
```

I want to from the array remove any objects that have the same `id` *AND* the same `name` as the `newHistoryObject`.

I have tried using lodash isEqual, but of course this did not work, since there are other properties that could differ.

I also tried like this:

```
var temp = _.filter(historyList, function(item) {
    if (newHistoryObject.name !== item.name &&
        newHistoryObject.id !== item.id) {
        return item;
    }
});
```

This did not work. It only keeps the object that is a duplicate here, and throws away the others.

The result I want is an array where any object that has the same `name`and `id`as the "outside" object, in this case like this:

```
var temp = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Donna', data: 'phone: 903489349'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 1'}
]
```

Comment: I have done that now

Comment: You say "*I want to from the array remove…*" but the example shows creating a new array. Which do you want?

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution in plain Javascript with a temporary object `this` and [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var historyList = [{ id: 1, name: 'Donna', data: 'phone: 903489349' }, { id: 2, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 1' }, { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 2' }],
    newHistoryObject = { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'phone: 03492' },
    filtered = historyList.filter(function (a) {
        return a.id !== this.id || a.name !== this.name;
    }, newHistoryObject);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I have now updated the question which will perhaps impact your answer, I was not clear enough before.

Comment: It seems weird to me to combine the two properties like this, what if there is a `1` somewhere in the `data` property? Will this really only catch where both name *and* id is the same?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var arr = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'phone: 03492'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Donna', data: 'phone: 903489349'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 1'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 2'}
];
var map = {}; 
arr.forEach(function(value,index){ 
    var obj = JSON.stringify({id:value.id, name:value.name}); 
    if (!map[obj])
    { 
       map[obj] = true; 
    }
    else
    { 
       arr.splice(index,1); 
    } 
});
console.log(arr); //final output
```

> I want to from the array remove any objects that have the same id AND
>   the same name as the newHistoryObject.

```
historyList.forEach(function(value,index){
  if ( value.id == newHistoryObject.id && value.name == newHistoryObject.name )
  {
    historyList.splice(index,1);
  }
});
console.log(historyList);
```

Comment: Replacing `JSON.stringify(...)` with `value.id + value.name` should have significant performance gains. Also,  `!map[obj]` should be `!map.hasOwnProperty(obj)` since you only want to check own properties (or use `map = Object.create(null)`). Also, pretty sure if you splice the current member, *forEach* will skip the next.

Comment: @RobG I agree but `value.id + value.name` will give wrong result in case `id = ''` and `value = '1Amy';` . So, concatenation alone will not solve the problem

Comment: Sure, or for id:1, name:23 and id:12, name:3 so better to compare property for property.

Comment: @RobG true, I assumed that this is not a exact use case of OP, in practice he/she may have more attributes to compare with. But i agree on principle that concatenated string will make for a faster key comparison with all its limilations, just that it won't be completely safe.

Comment: I realized I was not clear at all and have now updated my question, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

I try to use a map.

```
var map={};
list.forEach((o)=>{
  if(!map[o.id+o.name]){
    map[o.id+o.name]=o;
  }
});
var newlist=[];
for(var key in map){
  newlist.push(map[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good ideas, here's an attempt to munge the best of them together. It uses *reduceRight* to iterate backwards over the array, keeping another array of id and name values used to checked each object in the original array with *some*. If a match is found, it's removed.

*some* is handy as it returns as soon as a match is found.

The only catch is that it keeps the last instance of a copy, you might want the first.

```js
var data  = [
             { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'phone: 03492'},
             { id: 1, name: 'Donna', data: 'phone: 903489349'},
             { id: 2, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 1'},
             { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 2'}
            ];

data.reduceRight(function(acc, v, i) {
  if (acc.some(function(obj){return v.name == obj.name && v.id == obj.id})) {
    data.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    acc.push({id:v.id, name:v.name});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

document.write(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/},{/g,'},<br>{'))
```

If arrow functions are allowed, then the test becomes:

```
if (acc.some(obj => v.name == obj.name && v.id == obj.id))
```

#### Edit

Since you've changed the question, the function needs a small adjustment, but becomes more efficient:

```js
var data  = [
             { id: 1, name: 'Donna', data: 'phone: 903489349'},
             { id: 2, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 1'},
             { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 2'}
            ];

var checkObj = { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'phone: 03492'};

data.reduceRight(function(acc, obj, i) {
  if (obj.name == acc.name && obj.id == acc.id) {
    data.splice(i, 1)
  }
  return acc;
}, checkObj);

document.write(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/},{/g,'},<br> {'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I focused on a solution that edited the `historyList` object in-place, since that seems to be a requirement of the original question.

```js
var historyList = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Donna', data: 'phone: 903489349'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 1'},
    { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'address: Street 2'}
];

var newHistoryObject = { id: 1, name: 'Amy', data: 'phone: 03492'};

for (var i = 0; i < historyList.length; i++) {
  if (historyList[i].id == newHistoryObject.id &&
      historyList[i].name == newHistoryObject.name) {
    historyList.splice(i--, 1);
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(historyList));
```